# What are the methods to measure drag caused by an airfoil in a common high school labatory?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics, home-experiment, lift

I am currently planning to do an investigation on aircraft flaps. I am trying to find a correlation between the angle of the flaps setting and the lift-drag ratio (coefficient of lift over the coefficient of drag). Is there any simple way to estimate the drag produced by the wings? Will it work if let's say, I compare the wind speed in front of and behind the wings? Thanks!

Comment: Are you more interested in experiment or calculation? I would expect the maths would be pretty far beyond most high school students. Most such calcs would be 2nd or 3rd year university, and not trivial for them. So maybe some kind of wind tunnel experiment?

Comment: @BillOnne yes I'm planning to do a simple wind tunnel test. What methods can I use to measure drag? I already found a way to measure lift force

Comment: I've never built a wind tunnel myself. I just did a Google search for diy wind tunnel and there are many hits. Maybe if you are feeling keen and do some work on this you could report back how it went? Maybe you can get drag by changing your mounting orientation on the measuring device?

Comment: "labatory"?     Spelling?

Comment: It works if you're able to measure the whole velocity field in a section in front and in a section behind the airfoil, and find the drag from the integral balance of momentum, here for a sketch of the control volume: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Control-volume-for-the-2-D-momentum-deficit-method-to-determine-the-profile-drag_fig10_268381575. Otherwise you can measure it with a balance. Take in mind that drag of airfoil is difficult to measure, because it is only a fraction of the lift and errors, accuracy, influence of the experimental setup (requiring corrections) make uncertainty huge